# Using comma seperated values in List in SOQL QUERY 'IN' clause

Tags: apex, soql

I'm trying to use comma separated values of a List in SOQL IN Clause but it return records for only the first value on the List. 
Below is the code.

```
//Putting values from custom setting to list separated by comma (,)
List<String> lstMappingCustomer = Constants__c.getValues('MAPPING_CUSTOMER').Value__c.split(',');
//This returns 4 customer Name that I've added on custom setting
System.debug('MAPPING CUSTOMERS : ' + lstMappingCustomer);
List<Customer__c> tmpLstCustomer = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Customer__c 
                                        WHERE Name IN: 
                                        lstMappingCustomer
                                        ORDER BY Name ASC];
                                        System.debug('tmpLstCustomer : ' +tmpLstCustomer);
```

So on debugging tmpLstCustomer I only get the results for the first value in lstMappingCustomer and the rest gets ignored.

Any way around for this? Or anything that I'm doing incorrectly.

Comment: Are you sure you have records available in your system and you are passing correct Name?

Comment: Yes.. 100% sure.. is this the right way of doing it?

Comment: after splitting the string, can you add to list of string through looping. Use new list of string variable in your query.

Answer (score 1):

Please test these 3 scenario. Your code should work!!!

- Pleas check your lstMappingCustomer field values. I am thinking it
  returns null value.
- In case if it returns value I don't think its name field value.Please
  cross verify it once.
- ***and one important thing*** "*your custom setting names  values are not present in your object(Customer__c) name field. Please add that
  custom setting name value to your object name value. It should return
  values for you*" *otherwise you will get null.*

**In your case object contains only one mathching value so you are getting first value.**

This is simple query I have checked in my org for testing purpose.its working for me.In your case also it should work if you get the values in the list

```
 SELECT Id,Name FROM Account WHERE Name IN ('Test2','Account2','Air France')
```

Let me know still you are facing any problem